# Getting a unique id for a function object in PHP 5.3

Tags: php, spl, uid

I have tried using `spl_object_hash`, however it apparently doesn't work with function objects.

So how can this best be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function object is an object like any other. `spl_object_hash` should work for them as well. I also cannot find any reference in the documentation about this not working.

I actually tried it, and it seems to work just fine:

```
<?php
class x
{
    function __invoke()
    {
        return 'Test';
    }
}

$x = new x;
echo $x(); // Test
echo spl_object_hash($x); // The hash
```

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted the output. Actually `spl_object_hash` had choked on an array instead.